# Node-red to Apache Kafka Connectivity

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, node-red

I have kafka installed in a ubuntu server, and node-red is in my personal laptop. I want to send data from node-red to the kafka topic.

I tried using the kafka node in node-red to connect, but I am getting error like "Client is not a constructor". Also I am bit confused between the listeners and advertised listeners configuration. How should I configure the server.properties file for the same, and also which nodes should I include the node-red flow to achieve this, please suggest me some ways.

I expect that if I send some message from node-red, I should be able to see the same in kafka topic.

Comment: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Hi, Sure, thanks for the link, I am going thru it, But what if its a MQTT Message want to be consumed? @cricket_007

Comment: Then you'd have to find an MQTT proxy if you want to combine that with Kafka. For example, Kafka Connect or maybe Streamsets

Comment: yes completed the flow yesterday using kafka connect.